# WebSocket.acceptWithActor and @Inject() in the Actor (Play 2.5)

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework, akka, guice, playframework-2.5

`WebSocket.acceptWithActor` instantiates a new Akka actor without making use of Guice.

With Play 2.4, using the injector for my actor was still possible by importing `play.api.Play.current`.

Snippet from [ReactiveMongo documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html):

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future

import play.api.Play.current // should be deprecated in favor of DI
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

import play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONCollection

object Foo {
  lazy val reactiveMongoApi = current.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi]

  def collection(name: String): Future[JSONCollection] =
    reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection](name))
}
```

**But in Play 2.5, `play.api.Play.current` is deprecated.** How can I still inject `ReactiveMongoApi` in my actor? What is the recommended way of using an instance of `ReactiveMongoApi` in my actor?

Here is my code which works with Play 2.4 because my custom actor class `ClientActor` has access to `ReactiveMongoApi` through `current.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi]`:

```scala
@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {

  val midiDiscoveryActor = system.actorOf(MidiDiscoveryActor.props, "midi-discovery-actor")
  val midiActor = system.actorOf(MidiActor.props(midiDiscoveryActor), "midi-actor")

  def index(page: String) = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(page))
  }

  def bidirectional = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request => out =>
    ClientActor.props(out, midiActor, midiDiscoveryActor)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Quoting [James Roper](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/QzCHWAB1nQM):

> The helpers that Play provides for dependency injecting actors are suited for a limited number of use cases.  Though, the helpers are really just very thin wrappers over some common requirements - they're not needed at all.  In the case Play's WebSocket actor support, the thing is, generally you want to manually instantiate the actor since you have to somehow pass it the out ActorRef.  So, you can either do this using Guice assisted inject, and define a factor interface that takes the out actor ref (and whatever other arguments you want to pass to it), or simply instantiate it manually, passing dependencies from the controller to the actor, for example:
>
> ```
> class MyController @Inject() (myDep: MyDep) extends Controller {
>   def socket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, String] { request => out =>
>     MyWebSocketActor.props(out, myDep)
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Play 2.5 has built in support for DI.

MidiActor signature needs to be modified as said below.

```
class MidiActor@Inject() (configuration: Configuration,  @Named("midi-discovery-actor") midiDiscoveryActor: ActorRef) extends Actor with InjectedActorSupport{
.......
}
```

Create new Module and enable in application.conf

```
play.modules.enabled += MyModule

class MyModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure = {
    bindActor[MidiDiscoveryActor]("midi-discovery-actor")
    bindActor[MidiActor]("midi-actor")
  }
}
```

Change your controller as below

```
@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (system: ActorSystem,@Named("midi-actor") midiActor: ActorRef,
@Named("midi-discovery-actor") midiDiscoveryActor: ActorRef) (implicit ec: ExecutionContext)  extends Controller {

  def index(page: String) = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(page))
  }

  def bidirectional = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request => out =>
    ClientActor.props(out, midiActor, midiDiscoveryActor)
  }

}
```