# How to Inject() into a class with constructor parameters?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, actor

I have a `WebSocket` controller which creates per connection actor handler:

```
class WebSocketController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit exc: ExecutionContext) {
  def socket: WebSocket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef { out => // Flow that is handled by an actor from 'out' ref
      WebSocketActor.props(out) // Create an actor for new connected WebSocket
    }
  }
}
```

And inside the actor handler I need to work with `ReactiveMongo`:

```
trait ModelDAO extends MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents { 
  val collectionName: String
  ...
}
class UsersCollection @Inject()(val cc: ControllerComponents,
                                val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi,
                                val executionContext: ExecutionContext,
                                val materializer: Materializer)
  extends AbstractController(cc) with ModelDAO {
  val collectionName: String = "users"
}
```

So, the usual way is to @Inject() `UsersCollection` in the target class. But I can't do something like:

```
class WebSocketActor @Inject()(out: ActorRef, users: UsersCollection) extends Actor { ... }
```

Because instances of actor creates inside `WebSocketActor` companion object:

```
object WebSocketActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new WebSocketActor(out))
}
```

How do I use `UsersCollection` inside the `WebSocketActor`?

Comment: Might this be related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45774470/1080523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **create actor** who's dependencies will be injected automatically by Play. No problem. (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAkka)

**But** in case of web sockets, **Props** of the actor is expected, but not Actor (or ActorRef) itself.

```
ActorFlow.actorRef { out => // Flow that is handled by an actor from 'out' ref
   WebSocketActor.props(out) // <- ACTOR IS NOT CREATED HERE, WE RETURN PROPS
}
```

So there is no way to do it automatically in this case (At least I didn't find it).

What you can do is to pass `UsersCollection` manually.

```
class WebSocketController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, usersCollection: UsersCollection)(implicit exc: ExecutionContext) {
  def socket: WebSocket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef { out => // Flow that is handled by an actor from 'out' ref
      WebSocketActor.props(out, usersCollection) //<- ACTOR IS NOT CREATED HERE, WE RETURN PROPS
    }
  }
}
```

Noticed that I injected `UsersCollection` into `WebSocketController` and pass it to props.

Simple and I do not see any disadvantage.

Comment: I guess the question is rather how to inject an `ActorRef`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, disadvantage is in those I have more collections(users, tables etc.). Is it normal to pass it all manually to the actor?

Comment: If only this actor has multiple dependencies, then it is ok to pass them manually. But if you have multiple actors which has a lot of dendenices, I would wrap them into some Wrapper class, for ex: class @Singleton ActorDependencies @InjectI()(dep1: Dependency1, dep2: Dependency2...). And in Actors I would have class WebSocketActor (dependencies: ActorDepenencies)

Answer (score 0):

I have an event handler module inside my play app that basically instantiates all actors upon application startup. event handlers are all actors so you could do it like this:

```scala
class EventHandlerBootstrap @Inject() (system: ActorSystem, app: Application) {
  EventHandlerBootstrap.handlers.foreach {
    case (h, n) => system.actorOf(Props(app.injector.instanceOf(h)), n)
  }
}

//These Class[_ <: EventHandler] are classes of user defined actors each with their own
// dependencies which guice will take care of automattically.
object EventHandlerBootstrap {
  val handlers: Map[Class[_ <: EventHandler], String] = Map(
    classOf[UserRegisteredHandler] -> "user-registered-handler",
    classOf[CustomerOrderCreatedHandler] -> "customer-order-created-handler",
    classOf[DisputeClosedHandler] -> "dispute-closed-handler",
    classOf[Throttle] -> "throttle"
  )
}
```

and inside the module i run the bootstrapper like this:

```scala
class EventModule extends ScalaModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind[EventHandlerBootstrap].asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

if you're ofcourse not eager to blindly follow my recipe you can still take out the fact that injecting your actors and their dependencies is fully supported by guice as shown above. Hope It'll help